# Extent of support for using Vulkan Swapchain Images as Transfer Destination

Tags: graphics, specifications, vulkan

In my Vulkan backend implementation I currently check the supported usage flags for the Swapchain and then proceed to either use copy commands or a fall-back render pass to draw to the back buffer from an intermediary Render Target. I wanted to know whether this check is required or is it safe to assume that the Swapchain Images allow usage as a Transfer Destination on typical Desktop hardware.
Also, if anyone knows about Vulkan implementations that do not allow Copying to Swapchain Images, I'd appreciate it if you could share. This is mostly for the sake of curiosity rather than solving a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [Vulkan Hardware Database](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listdevices.php?platform=windows).

I couldn't find anywhere which summarized the data, but if you click on a device from the list then click onto the `surface` tab, then on the `surface properties` tab you can see `supportedUsageFlags` in the table and look for `TRANSFER_DST_BIT`.

I only looked at a few and they all had `TRANSFER_DST_BIT` present. I believe the database and code for the viewer are open source, so perhaps you can find a better way to mine the particular information you're after.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'd checked the Vulkan Hardware Database but, as you mentioned, checking the Swapchain Image properties was somewhat cumbersome. I will look into extending it for my specific needs. I'll wait for a week or two to see if someone does know of a platform where copying to the Swapchain is not allowed and if there isn't an answer by then, I'll mark the question as answered and close it.